# Flutter app, Theme.of(context) style doesn't work on text

Tags: flutter

Trying to apply a text color to my header tiles in my list view. I define a headline text style with red text color (yes I have also tried this with Colors.red).

When I create the tile, I use the function _headerTile. Trying to load the style via Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline. However the text does not use ANY of the three properties I have defined in headline when I do this.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text(
              'App',
            )),
            body: _buildList(context)),
        theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1),
                fontSize: 72.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) => ListView(
      children: [
        _headerTile(context, "About Us")
      ],
    );

ListTile _headerTile(BuildContext context, String title) => ListTile(
      title: Text(title,
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
    );
```

Comment: where are you calling the _headerTile?

Comment: my _buildList function. I will add

Answer (score 6):

It's because you are calling `Theme.of(context)` using the same context that is passed to `MyApp`'s `build` function. This means that the `ThemeData` returned by it will not be the one you have defined for the `MaterialApp`.

When you get a widget's state by calling `WidgetName.of(context)`, you basically use that context to look upwards through the widget hierarchy (all the parents of the widget to which that context belongs) until a widget state of that specific type is found. The context you are using belongs to the `MyApp` widget, which is the parent of the `MaterialApp` widget.

Try using `routes` or `onGenerateRoute` instead of `home` - this will give you a context to build your routes that sits below the `MaterialApp` widget, so that when you call `Theme.of(context)` it will return the expected `ThemeData`.

Answer (score 2):

Ovidiu was right about it using the wrong context. So instead I turned my buildList function into its own StatelessWidget

```
class List extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        _headerTile(context, "About Us")
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Your text doesn't use any of the these three properties because 
 .textTheme.headline is predefined in text_theme.dart . When you define
 .textTheme.headline , it styles it according to predefined style
 described in text_theme file. You can see the changes by using 
.textTheme.display1 or .textTheme.display2 . If you want your custom style 
you can do it this way :
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text(
                  'App',
                )),
            body: Text("MyApp",style: heading,),
       )
    );
  }
}



final heading =  TextStyle(fontSize: 60.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    color:Colors.green
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `MaterialApp` that exists after your build. Then it won't overwrite your customization.