# TextStyle doesn't identify accentColor and returns the wrong color

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, material-ui

In MaterialApp in theme, I am setting heeadline6's color with already set accentColor. But when I try to display text with headline6 textTheme, it gives me the wrong color, although every other parameter is correct.

```
theme: ThemeData(
   accentColor: const Color(0xffAEB8C4),
   textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline6: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
          fontSize: 50,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
   ),
),
```

This is the color

[image: 0xffAEB8C4]

And here is the code, Where I use headline6:

```
child: Text(
            "RLabs",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
          ),
```

And yet somehow I get the text with another color.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest storing the constant accent color in a separate palette class.
Example -

```
Palette{
  static final accentColor = Color(0xffAEB8C4);
}
```

Then

```
theme: ThemeData(
   accentColor: Palette.accentColor,
   textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline6: TextStyle(
          color: Palette.accentColor,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
          fontSize: 50,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
   ),
),
```

Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57671823/6051666) answer to get clarification on why Theme.of(context) doesn't work in your specific case

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! And I understand now, why it wouldn't work the way I wanted it to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help you https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_palette. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can give direct color to TextStyle.

```
theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: const Color(0xffAEB8C4),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline6: TextStyle(
            color: const Color(0xffAEB8C4),
            fontFamily: 'Lato',
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            fontSize: 50,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I know, but I want to make the code as simple as possible